# Поставить несколько слешей и по такой ссылке открыть изначальную страницу

Tags: редирект, php, битрикс

В битриксе в линк можно поставить несколько слешей и по такой ссылке спокойно открывается изначальная страница. Решил написать редирект. Не вижу ошибку, первый в жизни скрипт, сами понимаете. В общем *HELP.*

```
<?php

$urlvar=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];// получили урл без http:\\
$dlinna=strlen($urlvar)-4;//длинна строки -4
$search_slashes=(substr($urlvar, $dlinna, -1));//берем из конца урла 4 символов без последнего
$howmatch=similar_text($search_slashes, "///");//сколько слешей ? /max3/
$slash="/";

if ($howmatch=3) { //если 3 слеша
$tmpvar=substr($urlvar, 0, strlen($urlvar)-4);// отрезаем 4 символа
$vivod=$tmpvar.$slash;//+ слеш в конце
}

elseif ($howmatch=2) {//если 2  
$tmpvar=substr($urlvar, 0, strlen($urlvar)-3);
$vivod=$tmpvar.$slash;
}

elseif ($howmatch=1) {//если 1
$tmpvar=substr($urlvar, 0, strlen($urlvar)-2);
$vivod=$tmpvar.$slash;
}

else $vivod=$urlvar;

echo $vivod;

header("Location: http://"."$vivod");

?>
```

Comment: [Как убрать повторяющиеся слэши в php?][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/143110/как-убрать-повторяющиеся-слэши-в-php

Comment: А можно всё это уложить в одну-две строчки кода, **точно иллюстрирующие** вопрос? Можно даже в одну: привести пример URL, переход по которому вызывает вопросы. Потому что разбираться в ваших манипуляциях и гадать что у них на выходе - не интересно.

Comment: Есть странички в битрикс, заканчиваются слешом, если ручками слешов добавить 404 не вылезает, пытался сделать редирект с site.ru/page24/// на site.ru/page24/

Comment: dekameron, спасибо регулярка супер, но при размещении в header.php происходит зацикливание.

Comment: Вот я дурак, = это присваивание а не равно.